# How to install scripts from pyproject.toml?

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry, uvicorn

I have this snippet in my pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
devel = "uvicorn api:app --reload"
prod = "uvicorn api:app"
```

I install it as mentioned in [poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts)

```
(wowtcg-tracker-api-dIKBwUYp-py3.10) bastakka@Karel-NTB:/m/c/U/b/D/P/I/w/wowtcg-tracker-api (main↓2|✚9…9)
» poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file

Package operations: 38 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing idna (3.3)
   ...
  • Installing yapf (0.32.0)
(wowtcg-tracker-api-dIKBwUYp-py3.10) bastakka@Karel-NTB:/m/c/U/b/D/P/I/w/wowtcg-tracker-api (main↓2|✚9…9)
»
```

But there were no scripts generated from this command.

Poetry can't run them

```
…-tracker-api-dIKBwUYp-py3.10) bastakka@Karel-NTB:/m/c/U/b/D/P/I/w/wowtcg-tracker-api (main↓2|✚9…9)
» poetry run prod

  ModuleOrPackageNotFound

  No file/folder found for package wowtcg-tracker-api

  at ~/.poetry/lib/poetry/_vendor/py3.10/poetry/core/masonry/utils/module.py:63 in __init__
       59│                             "from": str(src.relative_to(self._path)),
       60│                         }
       61│                     ]
       62│                 else:
    →  63│                     raise ModuleOrPackageNotFound(
       64│                         "No file/folder found for package {}".format(name)
       65│                     )
       66│ 
       67│         for package in packages:
…-tracker-api-dIKBwUYp-py3.10) bastakka@Karel-NTB:/m/c/U/b/D/P/I/w/wowtcg-tracker-api (main↓2|✚9…9)
»
```

And there are none in the venv bin either

```
…-tracker-api-dIKBwUYp-py3.10) bastakka@Karel-NTB:/m/c/U/b/D/P/I/w/wowtcg-tracker-api (main↓2|✚9…9)
» ls /home/bastakka/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/wowtcg-tracker-api-dIKBwUYp-py3.10/bin
activate          dotenv*                  pip*               pyreverse*   watchgod*
activate.csh      epylint*                 pip3*              python@      wheel*
activate.fish     get_objgraph*            pip-3.10*          python3@     wheel3*
activate.nu       httpx*                   pip3.10*           python3.10@  wheel-3.10*
activate.ps1      isort*                   prisma*            symilar*     wheel3.10*
activate_this.py  isort-identify-imports*  prisma-client-py*  undill*      yapf*
deactivate.nu     normalizer*              pylint*            uvicorn*     yapf-diff*
…-tracker-api-dIKBwUYp-py3.10) bastakka@Karel-NTB:/m/c/U/b/D/P/I/w/wowtcg-tracker-api (main↓2|✚9…9)
»
```

Am I missing something needed or doing something wrong?

Comment: This is not how `scripts` are meant to be used (they are not the same thing as `scripts` in _npm_). I would recommend reading the documentation again. In short the value should be a function, something like `package_name.sub_package_name:function_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tool.poetry.scripts` is used for ["scripts or executables that will be installed when installing the package"](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts). You'd have to drop the `poetry run` prefix to run them.

For development scripts I'd recommend something like [taskipy](https://github.com/illBeRoy/taskipy). e.g.

```
# pyproject.toml
[tool.taskipy.tasks]
devel = "uvicorn api:app --reload"
prod = "uvicorn api:app"
```

Then you can run something like `poetry run task devel`